# Hiding git branch information in oh-my-zsh

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

How do I remove / hide the git branch information that is displayed on my iTerm2 terminal? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: in your oh-my-zsh-config probably

Comment: `cat ~/.zshrc | grep -i git` will show you where in your config you are enabling the git information.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Agnoster theme, and this is one of the primary draws of this theme. Why do you want to disable it? It's in the theme file at `.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme`, but it seems like a better idea to use a different theme. If it's just about how long the line is and how far over it moves your cursor, you can use a modified theme, like this one that puts your cursor on a new line: https://gist.github.com/nweddle/e456229c0a773c32d37b

Comment: what theme, color and font are you using?

Answer (score 6):

If you have `agnoster` theme for `ZSH` then you could disable the git branch information by the following steps:

1. Open `agnoster.zsh-theme` theme config file - for example

   `vi ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme`
2. Inside the function `build_prompt() { ...}` just comment out the below line

   `# prompt_git`

Answer (score 2):

As denmch said in the comments, it looks like you're using the Agnostic theme. A quick and dirty solution would be to edit the `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme` file and comment out the lines that have the words `echo` and `branch`.

On the default file they are three:

`echo -n "${ref/refs\/heads\//$PL_BRANCH_CHAR }${vcs_info_msg_0_%% }${mode}"`

`echo -n $(hg prompt "☿ {rev}@{branch}") $st`

`echo -n "☿ $rev@$branch" $st`

Answer (score 2):

Most themes now use the `git_prompt_info` helper function. This function will not add GIT branch info to the prompt if the `oh-my-zsh.hide-info` git property is set to `1`.

To disable git branch information for all git repositories, enable the property globally:

```
git config --global --add oh-my-zsh.hide-info 1
```

The `agnoster` theme doesn't use the `git_prompt_info` but works similarly. It just expects a different property, `oh-my-zsh.hide-status`. So, to disable the GIT branch info with the `agnoster` theme, use the following:

```
git config --global --add oh-my-zsh.hide-status 1
```